# BigQuery Migration Dynamic Schema on Apache Beam

Tags: google-bigquery, window, apache-beam

I am trying to write an ETL from Mongo to BigQuery. Since the schema is not fixed in Mongo, I need to update the schema before streaming the data to BigQuery.

So I am using windowing with an side input for the `withSchemaFromView`.
When using the windowing for the schema I get an error:

> Attempted to get side input window for GlobalWindow from non-global
>   WindowFn

It seems that `BigQeryIO` uses a global window for the schema. Is there a solution for this?